# Convert Text file to Dictionary of Objects

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following class:

```
class Car
{ 
    public Make{get; set;}
    public Model{get; set;}
    public Year{get; set;}
    public Color{get; set;}

    public Car(string make, string model, string year, string color)
    {
        this.Make= make;
        this.Model= model;
        this.Year= year;
        this.Color= color;
    }
}
```

I have the following text file *"Carlist.txt"*:

```
Id,Make,Model,Year,Color
0,Toyoa,Corola,2000,Blue
1,Honda,Civic,2005,Red
```

I want to have a dictionary of the form:

```
Dictionary<string, Car>
```

Here is my code to read the text file and parse out the elements into a dictionary but I am not able to get this to work:

```
Dictionary<string, Car> result =
        File.ReadLines("Carlist.txt")
            .Select(line => line.Split(','))
            .ToDictionary(split => split[0], 
                          new Car(split => split[1], 
                                  split => split[2], 
                                  split => split[3], 
                                  split => split[4]));
```

What am I doing wrong? I keep getting the following error on each of the split elements in *new Car(*

> Error  CS1660  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

### Update:

Here is my current code with an auto increment key (*variable i*):

```
int i = 0;
Dictionary<int, Car> result =
          File.ReadLines(path + "Carlist.txt")
              .Select(line => line.Split(','))
              .Where(split => split[0] != "Make")
              .ToDictionary(split => i++, 
                            split => new Car(split[0], 
                                             split[1], 
                                             split[2], 
                                             split[3]));
```

Thus my textfile now looks like this:

```
Make,Model,Year,Color
Toyoa,Corola,2000,Blue
Honda,Civic,2005,Red
```

Comment: `split[0]` is a string, not an `int`. You need to *parse it to an int*

Comment: My apologies, I just updated my question.

Comment: You don't need to apologize...just think about how others are going to see your questions since we're not inside your head.

Comment: I am trying to select each line and split it @ each comma

Comment: `.ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => new Car(...));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of issue you need to solve.

Firstly each parameter of the ToDictionary method is a single delegate the syntax for this is:

```
.ToDictionary(split => int.Parse(split[0]), 
  split => new Car(split[1], split[2], split[3], split[4]));
```

As opposed to trying to pass a delegate in to each parameter on your Car constructor (as in the original code).

The second is that you will read your header line and create a Car with the headers as values, you will want to exclude this, one way could be to add this above your ToDictionary:

```
  .Where( split => split[0] != "Id" )
```

Here's a version that should do what you want

```
var result = File.ReadLines("Carlist.txt")
        .Select(line => line.Split(','))
        .Where( split => split[0] != "Id" )
        .ToDictionary(split => int.Parse(split[0]), split => new Car(split[1], split[2], split[3], split[4]));
```

Answer (score 2):

`File.ReadLines` returns an array of `strings`. You then `split` each string with gives you another array of `string`. `string` is not `int`, so you have to parse it. Also your second lambda was all messed up. Something like:

```
Dictionary<string, Car> result =
    File.ReadLines("Carlist.txt")
        .Select(line => line.Split(','))
        .ToDictionary(split => int.Parse(split[0]), 
                      split => new Car(split[1], 
                                       split[2], 
                                       split[3], 
                                       split[4]));
```

A couple of things to note, this will fail if that first element can't be parsed as an integer (which if you file actually does include those headers, it can't). So you'll need to skip the first row and/or add some error handling.

Answer (score 1):

For others who come here looking for CSV deserialization:

The approach of reading CSV and splitting on coma works for many scenarios, but will also fail in many scenarios. For example CSV fields that contain coma, fields with quotation or fields with escaped quotation. These are all very common, [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and valid CSV-fields used by for example Excel.

Using a library that fully supports CSV is both simpler and more compatible. One such library is [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). It has support for a wide variety of mappings if you need manual control, but in the case described by op it is as simple as:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set;}
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    List<Car> cars;
    using (var fileReader = File.OpenText("Cars.txt"))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(fileReader))
        {
            cars = csv.GetRecords<Car>().ToList();
        }
    }
    // cars now contains a list of Car-objects read from CSV.
    // Header fields (first line of CSV) has been automatically matched to property names.  

    // Set up the dictionary. Note that the key must be unique.
    var carDict = cars.ToDictionary(c => c.Make);        
}
```